# Transactions are getting stuck because of tperrno issues

Tags: queue, rhel8, tuxedo

After migrating the OS from RHEL-7.9 to RHEL-8 we are continuously receiving the below errors.

A system exception has occurred : Commit transaction failed: tperrno = 1, error text = <TPEABORT - transaction cannot commit>

A system exception has occurred : Enqueuing to QSpace [PPQ_SPACE1], Q [CPA] failed: tperrno = 13, [TPETIME - timeout occured]

A system exception has occurred : Enqueuing to QSpace [PPQ_SPACE1], Q [CPA] failed: tperrno = 12, [TPESYSTEM - internal system error]

Failed to open Resource Manager: tperrno = 16 error text = <TPERMERR - resource manager error

A system exception has occurred : Begin transaction failed: tperrno = 0 error text = <>

Tried to raise this issue with Tuxedo support and applied patch but still receiving this issues.

Comment: Maybe it is time to migrate to Enduro/X middleware, it has the same /Q API, and in case of an error, debug logging can be enabled with simplicity to get the root of the error. But if you still want to continue with Tuxedo, maybe check the ULOG entries.

Comment: Hello Madars Vi,

Thanks for the reply but we have to continue with Tuxedo middleware only. In ULOG we have observed tperrno errors only and all these errors are related to the tpcommit, tpeneque etc i.e  ATMI API related issues but we are not able to find any specific error message.

Comment: Did you try to recreate the tlog and qspace devices?

Comment: yes tried multiple times